# Why can't I use my enum type inside a switch expression?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've got an enum called `Category`, but with a few special attributes for translating the Enum into another langauge.

```cs
public enum Category
{
    [StringValue("Varm mat")]
    HotFood,
    [StringValue("Kald mat")]
    ColdFood,
}
```

I'm trying to map from the string value to the enum using a switch expression,
but I get a compilation error: `The type name 'HotFood' does not exist on the type 'Category'` (and similar for ColdFood).
The `GetStringValue()` method is an extension method we wrote for getting the StringValue attribute of the Enum.

```cs
public static Category MapStringToCategory(string stringValue)
{
    var thisOneWorks = Category.HotFood.GetStringValue(); // this debug line works fine
    return stringValue switch
    {
        Category.HotFood.GetStringValue() => Category.HotFood, // error: 'HotFood' does not exist on the type 'Category'
        Category.ColdFood.GetStringValue() => Category.ColdFood, // error: 'ColdFood' does not exist on the type 'Category'
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException($"No string value for {stringValue}")
    };
}
```

I can't wrap my head around why `Category.HotFood` works fine outside of switch expressions,
but not inside them.
I also tried with a regular switch statement, but same error.
Would appreciate some input.
I'm using C# 8 and .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Shouldn't case value be compile time constant?

Comment: The StringValue?

Comment: Aah, yes, you're right @MistyK. I tried with `string.Empty` and got a much more understandable error message :`A constant value is expected`

Comment: If you could post that as an answer, I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment - **Case** value should be known at compile time.